# How do I make edges go around a whole object?

Tags: mesh, objects, edges

I have this object and I want the highlighted edges go around the whole object (like the edges in the middle), so that I can split it in 4 parts. I'm kinda new to blender and would like to know how this works

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bR-hWPirFZQ

This should hopefully help you

Comment: This is called a loop cut, but you will need quad geometry. Hopefully in your case this should be easy, select everything in edit mode, then got to Face > Tris to quad. Then you can use the shortcut CTRL + R to add loop cuts

Answer (score 0):

In order to select an edge to go around the whole model press <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd>